# Aggregate by remaining columns in dataframe in r

Tags: r

I am wondering if there isn't a better way to aggregate the following series in a data frame without having to list all the remaining columns in my data frame X:

```
Date    Factor_1    Factor_2    Amount
14-Jan  A   x   270
14-Jan  A   z   303
14-Jan  A   x   547
14-Jan  A   z   285
14-Jan  B   j   800
14-Jan  B   k   697
14-Jan  B   j   380
14-Jan  B   k   694
```

In a normal aggregate, the standard way to aggregate would be:

```
aggregate(X$Amount, by = list(X$Date, X$Factor_1, X$Factor_2), sum)
```

Is there a way to aggregate by using different notation such as:

```
aggregate(X$Amount, by = list(X[,-ncol(X)]), sum)
```

The idea is too avoid having to type all factors in a large data frame and the result still be:

```
Group.1 Group.2 Group.3 Sum
14-Jan  A   x   817
14-Jan  A   z   588
14-Jan  B   j   1180
14-Jan  B   k   1391
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the formula method of `aggregate`.  Specify all the other variables in the dataset on the rhs of `~` as `.`.

```
aggregate(Amount~., df1, sum)
#    Date Factor_1 Factor_2 Amount
#1 14-Jan        B        j   1180
#2 14-Jan        B        k   1391
#3 14-Jan        A        x    817
#4 14-Jan        A        z    588
```

---

The equivalent `dplyr` method

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by_(.dots=names(df1)[-4]) %>%
    summarise(Amount= sum(Amount))
```

and the `data.table` way is

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, list(Amount= sum(Amount)), by = c(names(df1)[-4])]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, the dplyr method is perfect! It also allows for flexibility if only some of the variables need to be included!